# iOS GitHub Firebase Authentication

Tags: swift, firebase, github, firebase-authentication

I'm currently trying to implement Github as a sign-in feature for auth. I've already hooked up everything (URL type setup in Xcode, client and secret ID in firebase console etc.)

Following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/github-auth#swift_3), I realized that I'm not getting any response from the code it stated.

```
func authenticateGithub() {
        let provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "github.com")
//        provider.scopes = ["user:email"]
        provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
            print("Entered 2 \(credential)")
            if let error = error {
                print("Error in getting credential: \(error)")
                return
            }

            guard let credential = credential else {
                print("No credential received")
                return
            }

            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error in signing in with credential: \(error)")
                    return
                }

                // User is signed in
                if let authResult = authResult {
                    print("Signed in user: \(authResult.user.email ?? "Unknown Email")")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The culprit here seems to be `getCredentialWith(nil)`, but that's what the documentation said to do too. Any pointers to a potential solution is greatly appreciated, thank you!